# Woocommerce Remove Coupon Section from Checkout Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to remove the "Have a coupon" section that sits at the top of a Woocommerce checkout page (/checkout).

I would like to keep the coupon section on the Cart page, so I can't completely disable coupons, but would like it removed on the checkout page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );
```

Put this in your `functions.php` and this should do it.

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! super helpful! still works per Jan 2021

Answer (score 13):

There is two way one is already given in this question by Reigel.

If it is not working below is another code:

```
function hide_coupon_field_on_cart( $enabled ) {
if ( is_checkout() ) {
    $enabled = false;
}
return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled', 'hide_coupon_field_on_cart' );
```

Comment: This is clever but it does require more processing than Reigel's. So I have up-voted his.

Comment: True i have given you another option that is it not for upvote i am giving the answers

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the other answer did not work for me.

Comment: Less code:

`function hide_coupon_field_on_cart( $enabled ) {
    return !is_checkout();
}`

Comment: Thanks for the alternate answer, yours worked for me

Comment: This indeed means more computations, but also allows to use other conditions, for example, i'm using this if a coupon was registered before the checkout page. 
```
function hide_coupon_field_on_cart($enabled) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $applied_coupons = $woocommerce->cart->get_applied_coupons();

    if (is_checkout() && !empty($applied_coupons)) {
        $enabled = false;
    }

    return $enabled;
}
```
Thanks

Comment: The first solution didn't work for me, this one (the second) work like a charm thanks !